# Set vibration for Samsung devices

Tags: android, android-notifications, samsung-mobile, android-vibration

I would like to modify the vibration of the Samsung devices for Android 4.x. What I exactly want to do is to turn the vibration ON or OFF and being independent of the call or notification volume.

This is what I would like to have:

- Normal: sound & vibration
- Only sound: sound & no vibration
- Only vibration: vibration & no sound
- Silent: no sound & no vibration

"Normal", "Only vibration" and "Silent" are easy, but I cannot get it to work with "Only sound". I observed that when it sounds, it will also vibrate, and thus **I cannot have it with sound and no vibration**.

I have tried with

```
AudioManager.setRingerMode()
```

but the only options are **RINGER_MODE_NORMAL**, **RINGER_MODE_SILENT** and **RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE**.
(There is no option for **RINGER_MODE_NORMAL_WITHOUT_VIBRATION**)

Then, I also added this code:

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), "vibrate_when_ringing", 0);
```

And it works for calls, but not for notifications. Incoming calls will not vibrate but if an email or WhatsApp or text/SMS arrives, then they vibrate.

This is deprecated now but it was perfect:

```
amanager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER, AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF); //Set it to never vibrate on ring:
amanager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_NOTIFICATION, AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF); //Set it to never vibrate on notify
```

So, any help with this?